# State whether true or false?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For positive integers $m$ and $n$, if $$\phi(mn)=\phi(m)$$ and $n>1$, then $n=2$ and $m$ is odd, where $\phi$ denotes  the Euler totient function.

State with justification whether the statement is true or false.
In my opinion I think the statement is true but I can't find the starting point for the proof.. it's really confusing.

Comment: What makes you think it’s true? Did you test some explicit numbers? What additional facts do you know about the totient function? What is the definition of the totient function? If you thought it was false, what precisely would be required to provide a counter example? Euler totient function is all about prime factors, what theorems have you seen about prime numbers and factor?

Comment: I know someone already gave you a detailed hint below, in just giving you examples of the types of things I would ask myself if I was assigned this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$:

$$\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n) \frac{d}{\phi(d)}$$

where $d=\text{gcd}\;(m,n)$

[For the proof, refer Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number theory]

$\textbf{Addition}$:

By this result, and your hypothesis

$$\phi(m)=\phi(m) \phi(n) \frac{d}{\phi(d)}$$

So $\phi(n) \frac{d}{\phi(d)}$ must be $1$. Since both factors are positive integers, $\phi(n)=1$ and $\frac{d}{\phi(d)}=1.$

$\phi(n)=1$ implies $n=1$ or $2$, but $n>1$ so $n$ must be 2.

Also$$\frac{d}{\phi(d)}= \frac{gcd(m,n)}{\phi(gcd(m,n))}=\frac{gcd(m,2)}{\phi(gcd(m,2))}=1$$ implies $m$ must be odd

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm trying to figure out. But I guess I don't know about the result you've stated that's why I can't start. Thankyou so much

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Break things into prime components and use $\phi(p^k*...*q^m) = (p-1)p^{k-1}*..... *(q-1)q^{k-1}$.  It will show you that if $\phi(n) =1$ then $n = 2$ and more.

Answer (score 1):

Unique prime factorization is your friend.

Let $\gcd(m,n) = \prod r_i^{v_i}$ where $r_i$ are prime.

Let $m = \prod p_i^{w_i} \prod r_i^{u_i}$ are the $p_i$ are prime distinct from $r_i$ and $u_i \ge v_i$

Let $n = \prod q_i^{j_i} \prod r_i^{z_i}$. ditto.  And $z_i > u_i$ only if $u_i = v_i$ and vice versa.

So $\phi(nm) = \prod q_i^{j_i-1}\prod (q_i-1)* \prod p_i^{w_i - 1}\prod (p_i-1) \prod r_i^{max(u_i,z_i)-1}\prod (r_i-1)$.

And $\phi(m) \prod p_i^{w_i - 1}\prod (p_i-1) \prod r_i^{\max(u_i,v_i) - v_i}\prod (r_i-1)$

Sooooo....  $\prod q_i^{j_i-1}*\prod (q_i - 1)*\prod r_i^{u_i - v_i} = 1$.

So all $q_i - 1 = 1$ so $q_i$ can only be $2$.  And $\prod q_i^{j_i-1} = 2^{j_1-1} = 1$ so $j_1= 1$.  So $m = 2$.

The $\gcd(2, m)$ must be either $2$ (if $m$ is even) or $1$ if $m$ is odd. So $r_i = 2$ and $u_i=v_i=1$ or $0$.

If $m = 2m'$ where $m'$ is odd then $\phi(nm) = \phi(2m) = \phi(2^2m') = \phi(2^2)\phi(m')$ whereas $\phi(m) = \phi(2m') = \phi(2)\phi(m')$.  But this implies $\phi(2^2) = 2 = \phi(2) = 1$.  So $m = m'$ is odd.

Comment: hmmm... might be easier to read if I broke it into cases... wouldn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Phi function is multiplicative.

Comment: Ok I know. And then..?

Comment: For *relatively prime* pairs.

Comment: This happens only when $m$ and $n$ are co prime